# Problema com o click em input

Tags: javascript, jquery, android

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação híbrida para mobile, utilizando HTML5 e JS. Estou com o seguinte problema: quando clico, por exemplo, em Apelido, ele abre a parte de Sexo. Porém, é um comportamento muito esquisito, ele somente acontece quando é a primeira vez que o campo é aberto, caso o campo já esteja com foco, ele procede corretamente. Outra situação que ocorreu: quando eu mudo o foco para outro campo, funciona perfeitamente.

Segue abaixo a imagem do problema. Ocorreu um click no apelido, e o que ele abriu foi a data de aniversário.

[image: O Click no Apelido]

Fiz um simulação no jsFiddle porem la funciona perfeitamente.

https://jsfiddle.net/h12uro5b/

Esta é a função que faço para gerenciar os clicks, utilizo isto para o campo que esta com foco, e o mesmo fica sempre no topo da pagina.

```
 var inputs = $('input').get();
 $(inputs).on('focus', function () {
     var pos = $(this).offset(),
         posFinal = pos.top - 55;
     $(this).closest('.upage').scrollTop(posFinal);
   });
```

Comment: Opa... como vc está gerenciando os clicks? tem um função click para cada ou vc fez um genérica e faz um filtro pelo id do item clicado?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta

Comment: @RenanRodrigues não há nada errado com seu código, isso ocorre com apps hibridos em geral, pois tem a ver com os pixels da tela, como você mesmo disse só ocorre no primeiro carregamento da aplicação, depois não ocorre mais, tenho o mesmo problema com o meu app mas até hoje sem solução.

Comment: Já tentou não gerenciar o focus? para testar, pois o focus é disparado primeiro que o click, e se no mobile browser tem um delay onde ele guarda dispara o focus, guarda a posição clicada e como vc move a tela, o click é pego no elemento abaixo.

Comment: @PauloRoberto desenvolvo apps utilizando cordova e nunca enfrentei este tipo de problema, será que ele gerencia de alguma forma isso? com o que vc desenvolve?

Comment: desenvolvo com Intel XDK, porem @PauloRoberto como posso fazer isto ?

Comment: @h3nr1ke  dependendo do Framework que você usa e da quantidade de scripts na pagina, ele fica meio lento e demora para fazer a primeira interpretação dos elementos na tela, a culpa disso é do WebView do Android, ja pesquisei muito sobre isso, mas até hoje não encontrei uma solução definitiva. Renan Eu desenvolvo usando o Jquery Mobile, as vezes o Phonegap mesmo, as vezes o Chocolate Ui, e o Framework7, depende do tipo de app e das funcionalidades dele.

Comment: Mais ai alguém tem a solução pro problema?

Comment: Reparei no exemplo que nem todos elementos têm id e name. É só no exemplo? Para o que percebi o constragimento só acontece no 1º focus quando a pagina abre. Já tentou no momento que a pagina abre simular o 1º focus? exemplo.: https://jsfiddle.net/h12uro5b/4/  (a variavel Focus1 é só para não correr toda função do focus a primeira vez)

Comment: @TiagoGomes Provavelmente simular um click resolveria minha duvida, porem é algo como uma gambiarra, tem que se levar em conta que estamos falando de um aplicativo mobile, e é extremamente deselegante abrir o teclado mediante a abertura de um tela. Mas entretanto é apenas no exemplo que está faltando.

Comment: Tem toda a rasão esqueci-me do pequeno e enorme detalhe que seria móvel e por isso apareceria o teclado. Acrescentei a função jquery blur para tirar o focus que deve corrigir esse contratempo. Ficou ultrapassado assim? https://jsfiddle.net/h12uro5b/5/     Não estou a colocar como resposta porque não é solução é só um remendo.

Comment: Conseguiu Resolver?

Comment: Não, estou justamente procurando sobre isto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem, eu tentaria fazer de uma forma totalmente diferente só pra testar. Existem milhares de formas pra isso. Exemplo:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  (function(input){
    input.addEventListener(focus, function(){
      //aqui o evento que vc quer disparar...
    }, true);
  })(inputs[i]);
};
```

A função lambda dentro do loop ajuda a isolar o escopo do evento, evitando relação entre eles.

E acredito que não é um problema comum de app hybrida. E sim uma questão de experiência com javascript e seus problemas.

Comment: Daniel bem vindo ao Stackoverflow. Aqui as perguntas e resposta são feitas de forma informal, por isso editei a sua resposta retirando as saudações.

Comment: Ok, obrigado. Lembrarei disso.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que o "scrollTop" está causando o comportamento estranho. Avalie se é realmente importante esse deslocamento automático porque em geral esse não é o comportamento esperado ao se preencher formulário num celular.

EDIT: corrigir erro de digitação

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim, isolar o BIND do jquery para cada input:

```
 var inputs = $('input');
 $(inputs).each(function(){
   $(this).on('focus', function () {
     var pos = $(this).offset(),
         posFinal = pos.top - 55;
     $(this).closest('.upage').scrollTop(posFinal);
   });
 });
```